# A question on a subgroup of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $X$ be an abelian group, $G$ a divisible subgroup of $X$ and $L$ a subgroup of $X$ such that $L\bigcap G\neq 0$. Let $nX=G$ for some $n$. For a positive integer $m$, define $H_{m}=\{x\in X;mx\in L\}$. Set $H=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}H_{nm}$. Then, $H$ is a subgroup of $X$ which contains $L$.

My question: Let $H=X$. Can we derive that $G=L\bigcap G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer is negative. Put $X=G=\mathbb Q$, $L=\mathbb Z$, and $n=1$. Then $H=X$ but $G\not\subset L$.